# Overleaf beamer presentation: \pause command

Tags: beamer, pause

I'm creating a beamer presentation and in one frame I would like to write three explanations of three different things. Example:

- Theory 1: explanation 1
- Theory 2: explanation 2
- Theory 3: explanation 3

Obviously each explanation can be of different length and It won't fit all in one slide. I was wondering if there is the possibility to use the \pause command in order to get in one slide the "Theory 1: explanation 1" in clear format, while "Theory 2" and "Theory 3" (without explanation) are at the bottom of the first slide but not in clear text.
Then, I would like to have a second slide with "Theory 1" (without explanation 1) not in clear text, whereas "Theory 2: explanation 2" is in clear text and "Theory 3" as Theory 1. Same for the third frame where we can find "Theory 1" and "Theory 2" (without explanation) not in clear text and we have "Theory 3: explanation 3".

What I did so far (the real content is not important):

```
\begin{document}  
\begin{frame}{Theory}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Theory 1} Explanation 1
    \pause
    \item \textbf{Theory 2} Explanation 2
    \pause
    \item \textbf{Theory 3} Explanation 3
    
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Someone deleted this answer that was almost perfect:

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Theory}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Theory 1} \only<1>{Explanation 1}
    \item \textbf{Thoery 2} \only<2>{Explanation 2}
    \item \textbf{Theory 3} \only<3>{Explanation 3}
    
    
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but in my document all the "Theory" are in clear text always.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us what you try so far. Writing some document example from scratch and don't knowing its contents is pure guessing  ... Help us to help you.

Comment: Please, edit your question and move content from comment to it. At this expand this code fragment to complete small document beginning with   `documentclass` and ending with `end{document}

Comment: I did it, but in this way I can see in clear "Theory 1: explanation 1" and in pause format the other two. I would like to see, in the first slide, only "Theory 1: explanation 1" clear and barely see Theory 2 and 3 (without the two explanations)